# Как корректно задать ограничение на pathParrent в intent-filter

Tags: android, uri, intent-filter, pathpattern, deeplink

Необходимо сделать DeepLink с переходом по адресу

> http://some.ru/link

При использовании следующей констукции:

```
    <data
       android:scheme="http"
       android:host="some.ru"
       android:path="/link"/>
```

Приложение корректно переходит по адресу http://some.ru/link, но если адрес указан как http://some.ru/link/, то ссылка уже не работает. 
   Каким образом сформировать path, не добавляя новый блок data, чтобы заставить прилодение реагировать только на ссылки со слешем и без, но не перехватывать случай, когда после слеша указаны какие то еще параметры, например http://some.ru/link/123?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `pathPrefix` вместо `path`:

```
<data
    android:host="some.ru"
    android:pathPrefix="/link"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

`path` для случаев, когда нужно полное совпадение